# How can I handle the alert (leave or cancel) on page close using Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

When the page close is triggered by the user, the JS alert pop-up is displayed.

[image]

Now how can I handle whether the user has clicked the **leave** or **cancel** button

Comment: You could disable all the form elements - that's a guess as I've never done this myself.  I tend to leave all browser actions exactly as they are.

Answer (score 0):

On leave the `unload` event will be triggered. I am not sure if it possible to catch the cancel properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const confirmed = window.confirm('are you sure?');

if (confirmed) {
  // user confimed
} else {
  // user did not confirm 
}
```

If you want to prevent users from leaving the page you must add canDeactivate guard to that component route definition.

More on it [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code main.html

```
<html>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 columns">
    <button type="" class="btn btn-info" ng-click=“submit()”> Submit </button>
</div>
</html>
```

this is the main html page once the submit is pressed the respective submit function will be called.

Here is my AlertpopupModal.html

```
<html>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="AlertpopupModal.html">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Do you want to leave this site</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <p> Changes that you made may not be saved </p> 
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                   ng-click ="leave()">Leave</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
                   ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Inject $modal into your controller.

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('AlertModalController', function($scope,$modal ) {
//code
});
```

Now add this code into your controller.

In this code I am simply calling the template through the id which I have used the modal template. And two functions are called for cancel and leave through which the modal will get closed as per the function.

```
$scope.submit= function ( ) {
  alertModalInstance = $modal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'AlertpopupModal.html',
    scope: $scope
  });

$scope.leave = function () {
  console.log("leave");
  alertModalInstance.close(true);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
  console.log("cancel");
  alertModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this piece of code is not relevant to the problem I have posted above. Your code may solve for custom modal or pop-up

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'leave-site';

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ]) beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    return false;
  }

}
```